# Как добавить данные в метод с помощью трейта, если разные родители?

Tags: php

Есть много классов, у которых разные родители `MyChildA, MyChildB, MyChildN`. Необходимо в каждый набор данных метода calc() добавить дополнительные данные. Так как родители классов разные, логично использовать трейт.

Родителей изменять не можем. Хотелось бы обойтись (в идеале) одной вставкой `use A;`, чтобы дополнительные данные добавились к существующим.

Как должен выглядеть трейт, чтобы методы calc() классов возвращали свои данные + дополнительные (`[1,2,100]` и `[3,4,100]` соответственно)?

```
trait A {}
class MyA {}
class MyB {}

class MyChildA extends MyA {
    use A;
    function calc() {
        return [1,2];
    }
}


class MyChildB extends MyB {
    use A;
    function calc() {
        return [3,4];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1. Использовать в трейте статический метод

```
trait A {

    static function calc() {
        return [100];
    }
}
class MyA {}
class MyB {}

class MyChildA extends MyA {
    use A;
    function calc() {
        $arr = [1, 2];

        return array_merge($arr, A::calc());
    }
}


class MyChildB extends MyB {
    use A;
    function calc() {
          $arr = [3, 4];
          return array_merge($arr, A::calc());
    }
}

$a = new MyChildA();
```

Вариант 2. Добавить псевдоним в классе

```
trait A {

    static function calc() {
        return [100];
    }
}
class MyA {}
class MyB {}

class MyChildA extends MyA {
    use A {
        calc as mainCalc;

    }

    function calc() {
        $arr = [1, 2];

        return array_merge($arr, $this->mainCalc());
    }
}


class MyChildB extends MyB {
    use A {
        calc as mainCalc;

    }
    function calc() {
          $arr = [3, 4];
          return array_merge($arr, $this->mainCalc());
    }
}

$a = new MyChildA();
$b = new MyChildB();

var_dump( $a->calc());
var_dump( $b->calc());
```

**Обновлено**:

```
trait A {

    function calc() {
        return array_merge($this->calcChild(), [100]);
    }
}
class MyA {}
class MyB {}

class MyChildA extends MyA {
    use A;

    function calcChild() {
        return [1,2];
    }
}




class MyChildB extends MyB {
    use A;

    function calcChild() {
          return [3, 4];
    }
}



$a = new MyChildA();
$b = new MyChildB();

var_dump($a->calc());
var_dump($b->calc());
```

**Обновлено**
На мой взгляд было бы логично НЕ использовать трейты, а сделать супер глобальный класс `My`

```
class My {
     function calc() {
        return array_merge($this->calcChild(), [100]);
    }
}


class MyA extends My {}
class MyB extends My {}

class MyChildA extends MyA {

    protected function calcChild() {
        return [1,2];
    }
}


class MyChildB extends MyB {

    protected function calcChild() {
          return [3, 4];
    }
}
```

---

*"...логично использовать трейт"* - это вряд ли :)

Comment: Почему трейт не логично использовать и что в таком случае использовать? 1 и 2 варианты подразумевают изменение метода класса, что не очень хотелось бы. Если сейчас надо перелопатить несколько классов и изменить метод, то такая или подобная ситуация вскоре возникнет еще раз. Или трейты не способны на такое? Чтоб воткнул use, а потом только внутри трейта копошиться и изменять классы.

Comment: я думал, что у Вас есть метод calc в трейте и Вы хотите его переопределить.  Обновил ответ. Что бы вызывать именно calc прийдется переименовать методы в классе. Ну или вызывать в трейте другой метод.

Comment: Трейты - это, грубо говоря, инклуд для классов. Аналог, думаю, friend функций в С++. То есть это не ООП, а некое обходное решение множественному наследованию. Один из главных принципов ООП - это инкапсуляция. Используя трейт не о какой инкапсуляции речь не идет )

Comment: Класс My очень логично, но у родительских классов еще куча родителей и последние в вендоре, поэтому общий родитель отпадает. Изменять название методов тоже нельзя/не желательно. Вариантов на самом деле не много, придется извращаться.

Comment: может тогда не название методов класса поменять а результирующий метод трейта в данном случае calc?

Comment: Да, в трейте метод с другим названием, в классах добавить еще один метод `twoCalc()` и из него дергать метод трейта. Это для того, чтобы метод класса `calc()` не пачкать методом трейта. Так может даже гибче получиться. Трейт только расширять будет, а управление этими расширенными возможностями останется в классе, в методе `twoCalc()`.

Answer (score 0):

посмотрите в сторону декоратора, или шаблонного метода.
шаблонный метод:

```
<?php

interface CalcInterface
{
    public function calc(): array;
}
```

```
<?php

trait CalcTrait
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commonData;

    protected abstract function getDataFromClass(): array;

    public function calc(): array
    {
        return array_merge($this->commonData, $this->getDataFromClass());
    }
}
```

```
<?php

class MyChildA extends MyA implements CalcInterface
{
    use CalcTrait;

    protected function getDataFromClass(): array
    {
        // TODO: Implement getDataFromClass() method.
    }

}
```